# How to Display a Node Label Using CSS / GRASS

Tags: neo4j, grass

I'm trying to include the node label in the visualisation so that the reader can immediately see the type of each node.

I've modified the stylesheet / GRASS to that a node of type 'Requirement' is:

```
node.Requirement {
  color: #CCCCFF;
  border-color: #CCCCFF;
  text-color-internal: #604A0E;
  diameter: 80px;
  caption:'<type> {requirement paragraph} - {name}';  
}
```

As you can see in the image the 'requirement paragraph' and 'name' are parsed but for some reason `'<type>'` (which works with connectors) is ignored. How can I get the label displayed or included as part of the node caption? Either is satisfactory.

Is there a reference somewhere that defines the allowed set of css descriptors and values for these visualisations?

[image: MV-03 Nodes representing Requirement Hierarchy - Note '<Type>' in Caption]

Answer (score 0):

It's a confirmed bug. Looks as though there is some debate how to select / present a label where a node has multiple labels - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5293